# angular 10 routing & navigation error with parameter

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular10

route array

```
const routes: Routes = [
 ...
  {path:'exam-list',component: ExamListComponent},
    {path:'exam-panel/:Id',component: ExamPanelComponent}
..
];
```

array imported

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
```

click event

```
onSelect(examdetails)
{
this.router.navigate(['exam-panel',examdetails.Id])
}
```

on click event onselect()

I got this error
**Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'exam-panel'**
with parameter
when I am using routerLink it's work fine but on click event is not working with router.navigate

**when i am using [routerLink]="['/exam-panel/',examdetails.Id]" it's working but when I am using "router.navigate" it naviagte first route exam-panel with parmeter ok, then automatically route to home page**

Answer (score 2):

As per mentioned in doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html, you can use either

navigateByUrl :

```
router.navigateByUrl(`/exam-panel/${examdetails.Id}`);
```

or using navigate :

```
router.navigate(['/exam-panel', examdetails.Id], {relativeTo: route});
```

relative to calls request navigation to a dynamic route path relative to the current URL.

please remember we often forget `/` it is a relative route. router. navigate needs a relativeTo parameter for relative navigation

Comment: router.navigateByUrl(`/exam-panel/${examdetails.Id}`) ? what is your examdetails.Id is coming? did you console log it?

Comment: examdetails is an json array come from API HTTP request

Comment: when i am using [routerLink]="['/exam-panel/',examdetails.Id]" it's working but when I am using "router.navigate" it naviagte first  route exam-panel with parmeter ok,  then automatically route to home page

Comment: router.navigate(['/exam-panel', examdetails.Id], {relativeTo: route}); did you try this adding ' / ' in router.navgate before exam-panel?

Comment: {relativeTo: route} can you explain to me what is "route"